# unable to setup cocoapods. Cocoapods setup problem

Tags: ios, git, github, flutter, cocoapods

I am trying to run my flutter app which is connected to Firebase, but when I try to run it on an iOS emulator, it shows these errors -

> Warning: CocoaPods installed but not initialized. Skipping pod >install.
> CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's >plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
> Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
> For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
> To initialize CocoaPods, run:
> pod setup
> once to finalize CocoaPods' installation.

So then I do "pod setup" but then it shows this error :

```
Cloning into 'master'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 14707, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (14707/14707), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14117/14117), done.        
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data 
remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling cocoapods? https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine or `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`

Comment: No not yet i havent tried uninstalling it

Comment: Tried still doesnt work..it is still showing that cocoapods are installed but not initialized when doing pod setup it now shows curl 56 transfer instead of 18

Answer (score 11):

For me it was due to cocoapods version. You can use this in your terminal:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5
pod setup
```

A workaround for this issue is here: 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41253

and also here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices

(I'm using macOS Catalina JIC)

Comment: Install the latest version or you'll be stuck with uninstalling this and updating, 1.7.5 is from 2019

Answer (score 4):

After updating the Flutter version, faced the same issue.

Tried `installing and uninstalling cocoapods` and still the same issue.

Finally, the issue resolved for me.

If you are using Android studio

```
File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be fixed now with flutter version `v1.9.1+hotfix.5` and above.

Try uninstalling all existing installations of cocoapods:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
brew uninstall cocoapods
```

Then install the latest version of cocoapods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

I can confirm that this is working with flutter `1.12.13+hotfix.9` (stable channel), cocoapods version `1.9.1`, on macOS Catalina `v10.15.4`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.0 -n /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: this version helped for flutter 2

Answer (score 2):

I was battling with this issue for days on end. The issue, for me was only when I use my Mac with M1 Chip. Initially, i got this error when I tried to add a audio player package to my project. After a week of seaching I came across the this solution[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66556339/4492564)

The worked perfectly until i needed to use a geolocation package and the issue was back again. After days of trying different solutions, I finally found that the solution that worked for me. I reinstalled cocoapods using brew. Once done, I closed the terminal, closed android studio then ran the following command on terminal open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app. Pod now installs with no issues and my project launches on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

In flutter, I solve this issue by opening an android studio with terminal

use this line on your terminal

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of an of existing answe, by @mpho. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. Remember to review all existing answers first.

Answer (score 1):

**This Problem comes to Macbook Pro M2 or Macbook M1  chip**

```
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform
        side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on
        the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see
      https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#insta
      llation for instructions.
```

**Solution:** This is work for me I have to suggest trying you and run this command.

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands in your terminal (but not in the AndroidStudio for example):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

After, run:

```
flutter build ios
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.2

sudo gem install cocoapods
```