# How to run CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, cocoapods, apple-silicon

I have a Flutter project that I'm trying to run on iOS. It runs normally on my Intel-based Mac, but on my new Apple Silicon-based M1 Mac it fails to install pods.

```
LoadError - dlsym(0x7f8926035eb0, Init_ffi_c): symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:74:in `cdn_url?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:36:in `create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:21:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1073:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Based on a Github workaround, I tried to run Terminal using rosetta, but the issue remains the same: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9907#issuecomment-655870749

Realising it's still early for Macs with Apple Silicon. Is there a way to make this work for the time being?

Comment: Was unable to get it working without rosetta following the accepted answer, on a new M1 mac mini. Once installed via rosetta, its probably still running in compatibility mode, even if rosetta is later turned off. The correct answer is `Valentin Briand`'s answer below. A very outdated version of Ruby is installed on Macs by default. Whats needed is to install a newer ruby (easiest via homebrew), config terminal to use that version and then just install cocoapods as normal

Answer (score 268, accepted):

EDIT: I recently disabled Rosetta, and Cocoapods runs just fine with the addition of the ffi gem.

For anyone else struggling with this issue, I just found a way to solve it. In addition to running terminal in Rosetta:

1. Right-click on Terminal in Finder
2. Get Info
3. Open with Rosetta

I installed a gem that seems to be related to the symbol not found in the error:

```
sudo gem install ffi
```

After doing this, cocoapods runs as expected.

Comment: This appears to work for me also. First, enable Rosetta on Terminal, install the ffi gem as documented above, then you can disable Rosetta.

Comment: @CliffHelsel What does this actually do? Install a separate version of `ffi`? If yes, which version is installed? If not, how does this actually help? Couldn't get it working yet, just trying to understand the details.

Comment: How did you manage to disable rosetta.. I don't see any way of doing it...

Comment: @MuhammadbinYusrat I think what he meant was unchecking the `Open with Rosetta` on the Terminal.

Comment: will there be any issues if don't disable rosetta?

Comment: "open using Rosetta" comes in general section. It’s for those who don’t know this option

Comment: Works fine. I need to keep "open with Rosetta" for the Terminal before calling `pod install` (if not, fails)
The next solution (with the `-x86_64` option) seems fine too, I'll try it.

Comment: This solution works pretty well for me without the need of "Open terminal with Rosetta".

Comment: This worked for me! I'm using Mac mini M1 & macOS Monterey. I installed cocoa pods using brew. Thank you for this answer

Answer (score 1047):

**2022 Nov Update**

If you can use Homebrew to manage cocoapods.

```
# Uninstall the local cocoapods gem
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

# Reinstall cocoapods via Homebrew
brew install cocoapods
```

---

**2021 Solution**

```
# STEP 1: Install ffi
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

# STEP 2: Re-install dependencies
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

*Additional Information*

#1 For anyone seeing the `arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable` error, you must first install Rosetta. Thanks, @Jack Dewhurst

#2 If you run `pod` commands pretty often, setting up an alias in `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile` might be handy. Thanks, @theMoonlitKnight for the suggestion.

```
alias pod='arch -x86_64 pod'
```

Comment: I had the same error and followed the above method and pod got installed. I am using MacBook M1

Comment: @Metropolis, does this mean everytime I'm gonna install new pods, I'll be using this command `arch -x86_64 pod install`?

Comment: These commands worked for me, whereas the original answer did not.  Thanks!

Comment: These commands work fine but you **have to use the system version of Ruby**. This did not work when i used Ruby 2.7 via rbenv

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct answer in 2021.

Comment: arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable

Comment: Not Working in MacMINI. Getting this error "arch: posix_spawnp: pod: Bad CPU type in executable"

Comment: So until there's an ffi update, instead of `pod install` we need `arch -x86_64 pod install` every time?

Comment: Rocking the M1X and this is still an issue, thanks for the help!

Comment: Put `alias pod='arch -x86_64 pod'` in .zshrc or .bash_profile to just type `pod install`

Comment: @xinyang I used these methods but for a firebase project its not working? any idea

Comment: For anyone seeing the `arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable` error you must first install Rosetta.

Comment: [!] Oh no, an error occurred. on Mac M1

Comment: Only partially works: pod install works fine. pod update has this error: LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Fr

Comment: Second step gives me this:
`arch: Can't find pod in PATH`

Comment: In my case. Just open `.zshrc` and put `alias pod='arch -x86_64 pod'` in the end of line

Comment: @NicolasBraun how did you get it to work with rbenv?

Comment: Feb 2022 - this works. Lots of outdated answers here because native Apple Silicon only started working recently with CocoaPod. Kudos for updating this answer!

Comment: You copied my answer and edited yours. That's not fair.

Comment: "2022 Update" works on M1!

Comment: If you get error to install cocoapods use "sudo gem install cocoapods
"

Comment: Can someone explain what arch -x86_64 is? Just curious because this is the second time I've revisited this page due to firebase issues and it's also a year later and only the 2021 answer works for me despite the timeline.

Comment: Installing cocoapods via brew doesn't work if you're trying to use `cocoapods-keys`. Installing ruby through homebrew worked for me (as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66556339/3462536) -- See issue thread in cocoapods-keys here: https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys/issues/217

Comment: Try not to use Terminal with Rosetta

Comment: Confirm this solution works for Monterey 12.3.1  (updated 2022-May)

Comment: after installing cocoapods using homebrew, i get command not found on zsh

Comment: I have a MacBook M1 and using Homebrew was the solution, thanks for sharing

Comment: M2 MacBook Air here. Confirming this worked. For those curious, Homebrew is a package manager for Mac. Installation instructions @ https://brew.sh.

Comment: `brew install cocoapods` gives an error:
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/xcodeproj
Target /usr/local/bin/xcodeproj
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/xcodeproj'

Comment: after updating to xcode 14, the cocoapods version from homebrew fails with errors

Comment: Use `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin` if you see error "You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory."

Answer (score 284):

#### TL;DR:

- Install your own version of Ruby with Homebrew / rbenv / RVM (e.g. `brew install ruby`)
- Add it and the gems binaries to your `PATH` and make sure the new version is used with `which ruby` (should be `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby` instead of `/usr/bin/ruby` if installed with Homebrew)
- Install CocoaPods with `sudo gem install cocoapods` (make sure `ethon` is at least version 0.13.0)
- Run `pod install`

#### Detailed answer:

All answers suggesting using Rosetta / `arch -x86_64` are workarounds and not quite solving the real issue that comes from the way RbConfig and the universal binaries work.

```rb
require 'rbconfig'

OSVERSION = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
ARCH = RbConfig::CONFIG['arch']
HOSTCPU = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_cpu']
BUILDCPU = RbConfig::CONFIG['build_cpu']
TARGETCPU = RbConfig::CONFIG['target_cpu']

puts "OS: #{OSVERSION}"
puts "Arch: #{ARCH}"
puts "Host CPU: #{HOSTCPU}"
puts "Build CPU: #{BUILDCPU}"
puts "Target CPU: #{TARGETCPU}"
```

If you call `ruby` on a file containing this code with the universal binary shipped with macOS, you will get the following result on an M1 Mac:

```
OS: darwin20
Arch: universal-darwin20
Host CPU: x86_64
Build CPU: x86_64
Target CPU: universal
```

As you can see, RbConfig was compiled for a « universal » CPU but built with an x86 CPU, and the `rbconfig.rb` file that was generated (see `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin20/rbconfig.rb`) consequently uses invalid information for the host CPU.

As `ffi` uses information from RbConfig (see https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/dfae59e293974efaa7b4d414e5116d7a2187a06e/lib/ffi/platform.rb#L61 and https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/e3f2cf9b82055709ddbeecbf77810f43438c4b64/spec/ffi/fixtures/compile.rb#L11), we end up with OP’s error message.

The solution is, therefore, to get a version of Ruby built specifically for arm64 by using either Homebrew, rbenv or RVM.

For Homebrew:

- Execute `brew install ruby`
- Add `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH` to your `.zshrc` (you can find your Homebrew installation directory with `$(brew --prefix)` if needed) (replace `3.0.0` with your actual ruby version)
- Execute `source ~/.zshrc` or restart your shell
- Make sure you are using the correct `ruby` binary by executing `which ruby` (should be `$(brew --prefix)/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`)
- Install CocoaPods with `sudo gem install cocoapods`
- Make sure you are using the correct `pod` binary by executing `which pod` (should be `$(brew --prefix)/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/pod`)
- Make sure `ethon` is version 0.13.0 or more with `gem info ethon`, otherwise run `sudo gem install ethon`
- Run `pod install`

#### Ruby won't come with future macOS versions by default

Moreover, it should be noted that `ruby` is still included in macOS only « for compatibility with legacy software », as evidenced by running `irb -v`, so this is probably a good opportunity to install your own version anyway:

> WARNING: This version of ruby is included in macOS for compatibility
> with legacy software. In future versions of macOS the ruby runtime
> will not be available by default and may require you to install an
> additional package.
>
> irb 1.0.0 (2018-12-18)

Sources:

- https://betterprogramming.pub/ruby-on-apple-silicon-m1-macs-fb159849b2f5
- https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/870

Comment: I was having exactly the experience you describe here. Tried applying the patch for `ethon` locally, but same `Segmentation fault` error was happening. What seemed to work for me (after having `ruby --version` as `arm64-darwin20`) was installing an older version of cocoapods (`1.5.2`)

Comment: Followed every step but was only able to make pods to install after manually installing the latest typhoeus/ethon gem from github (which already includes the patch in the latest commit as of March 28 3e87140...). thanks for diving deep into the issue!

Comment: ethon 0.13.0 is out. Thank you for your research.

Comment: "arch -x86_64" is a hack to just get things working, so this should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly.

Comment: @ValentinBriand I installed cocoapods using brew (/opt/homebrew/bin/pod) and it seems it all works (I am using ruby 3.0.1p64). I have ethon 0.12.0 on system ruby but that is not used.

Comment: I done the steps but which pod still gives me `/usr/local/bin/pod` path. Other steps are correct. How can I change pod location to ruby one?

Comment: @EmreÖnder do `which ruby` and `which gem` point to your Homebrew directory? If not, make sure that `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`

Comment: Yes `which ruby` and `which gem` shows me the correct directory. I uninstalled cocapods and reinstall it but didn't work. If I type `$(brew --prefix)/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/pod) install` rather than `pod install` It is working. Somehow, cocapod seems `usr/bin` rather than ruby path

Comment: This works. Forget the "arch -x86_64" circumvention in the other answers.

Comment: Thanks, this work for my. With my Xcode work space, also need to update Carthage script path to run success. Thanks again.

Comment: @EmreÖnder did you ever solve this? My M1 computer arrived today and can't get pod to point to the right ruby.

Comment: @MikePortanova I can help you. This works like a charm on my new iMac. First, run `brew --prefix`. Let's say the result is `mikes/path`. Then the changes for you would be `export PATH=mikes/path/opt/ruby/bin:mikes/path/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH`. Now `which ruby` and which pod should return `mikes/path/opt/ruby/bin/ruby` and `mikes/path/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/pod` respectively after you install ruby and cocoa pods as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Great answer! But `which pod` returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/pod` for me. It seems to run fine. How do I point to the correct pod binary?

Comment: @smileBot I think it's fine since `which pod` is pointing to your homebrew directory. Also, `/opt/homebrew/bin/pod` is likely a symlink so check where it points to.

Comment: @ValentinBriand Ok great. It is a symlink pointing to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/bin/pod`.

Comment: incredible!! after 2-3 hours of searching this fixed it.. thank you.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. It's not a workaround. Also note that if you installed cocoa pods before installing Homebrew, make sure to temporarily comment out the Homebrew path from your .zshrc file (or bash version), fully uninstall cocoa pods then add the Home-brew path back. Otherwise there terminal will use the non-Homebrew version of cocoa pods (at least that was my experience).

Comment: Do not read only the TL;DR, read the "For Homebrew" list that explains each step, in particular how to set up the PATH correctly.

Comment: Works fine! To have 'which pod' to show the proper version of CocoaPods, I had to restart my terminal. Followed the brew path.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Thank you for the detailed explanation. Worked fantastic on my 2021 MacBook Pro M1 Max.

Comment: I used `asdf` as my ruby version manager and this works fine...as long as you remember to remove any CocoaPods install (`sudo /usr/bin/gem uninstall cocoapods`) you may have done earlier with the ancient system Ruby, or ! That placed the `pod` command in `/usr/local/bin`, which was picked up first in my PATH instead of the asdf shim.

Comment: To set the Homebrew-installed Ruby to take priority over the system Ruby I need set ```if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fi``` on my `~/.zshrc`. For the complete guide see https://mac.install.guide/ruby/13.html

Comment: brew install ruby
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 1 formula.

Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
    arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.

Comment: Excellent answer and worked for me. Wish this could be pinned to the top

Comment: Thanks a lot to explain the main reason for understand the problem @ValentinBriand The 16k reputation should be yours xDDD

Comment: How do I add the path for this part?                                                                             " Make sure you are using the correct pod binary by executing which pod (should be $(brew --prefix)/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/pod) "

Comment: For the `PATH`, I added `export PATH="$PATH:\`gem environment gemdir\`/bin"` to my `~/.profile`

Comment: I tried so many solutions to make it work that it never did, it's been 3 months since I bought this mac, which is even damaged beyond salvage-able and even then, I've finally managed to make iOs development work. @1nstinct The problem was Rosetta, I disabled it for Terminal, then followed this answer, also reminding people to also uninstall `ffi` you won't need that with this answer, not uninstalling it will give architecture problems.

Comment: Interesting... after foraging the internet and encountering a lot of "noise", this finally worked

Comment: Add the Homebrew Ruby to PATH using sudo vim /etc/paths, and include /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin at the top of the list.

Comment: If you're here because of kotlin multiplatform check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/76800022#76800022

Comment: Ruby needed to be first in the path for `which ruby` to show the correct one. I added `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH` to `.zshrc`

Comment: Worked for me even without "which ruby (should be /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby instead of /usr/bin/ruby if installed with Homebrew)".

Answer (score 71):

To install completely cocoapods on Mac with M1 chip (Apple Silicon), please follow these steps:

1. Duplicate the Terminal application in the Utilities folder.
2. Right-click on the app and choose to Get Info.
3. Rename the other version of the app as you like.
4. Check the option "open with Rosetta".
5. Install Cocoapods with the command "sudo gem install cocoapods"
6. Type the command line "gem install ffi" to fix the ffi bundle problem.
   Now you can do a "pod install" without a problem.

Source : [iPhoneSoft](https://iphonesoft.fr/2020/11/19/astuces-mac-m1-homebrew-cocoapods-recuperation-windows)

Answer (score 39):

Simplest way I found :

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

`brew install cocoapods`

Comment: This works great. I also did `brew install libffi` for using some 3rd party libs with flutter. the `gem` shipped from macOS isn't cool.

Answer (score 27):

An alternative to running Terminal in Rosetta 2 is to set the architecture with `arch -x86_64`, as in the following:

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

To give credit where it is due, I found this solution here

[MacPorts bug tracker, issue #61545](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/61545), comment 7

Comment: Worked for me! Running on M1 pro

Answer (score 20):

1. ***Execute*** below to ***install*** the required ***ffi*** :

   `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
2. Instead of `pod install` use :

   `arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: wonderful! 

and it works also with `arch -x86_64 pod update`.
Note that I did `sudo gem install ffi` once before, don't know if it's important

Comment: Great @tontonCD , also you don't need `sudo gem install ffi` command because you're already doing same with sudo `arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`

Comment: I was having issue with `React/RCTBridgeModule.h` file not found.

Comment: this works fine with my M1 chip

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE 28th MARCH**

1- `arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin`

2- `arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi`

3- `pod install`

**No need to duplicate or Open with Rosetta**

Comment: I tried this but get a  `missing compatible arch` error

Comment: God bless you..I spent 10 hours on this, it worked.

Comment: when i runed pod install 
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Answer (score 12):

There is a much "better/easier?" way by way of using homebrew now that waters have settled, if you have homebrew install just run

```
brew install cocoapods
```

this will install ruby and libyaml as preconditions, so far this is the most straightforward way (and the one, most probably, to be recommended moving forward).

Comment: I confirm, only brew helped.

Comment: it will be installed, but not linked, if you try to link - error occure

Comment: works well in Jun 2023 on M1, Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Basically tried all solutions listed here.

```sh
$ arch -arm64 brew install cocoapods
```

finally did it for me.

Before doing that, be sure to have homebrew correctly installed with `/opt/homebrew` being the prefix. [This](https://noahpeeters.de/posts/apple-silicon/homebrew-setup/) article provides pretty good instructions on this.

Edit: Another option is to remove all your flutter and dart files and just use homebrew for the complete installation process as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIHzZlgsHNw). This also worked for me on M1 Pro.

Comment: worked for me as well.

Answer (score 11):

**Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Development**

If you're here because you got this error while running `kdoctor`

ruby@2.7 is working for me so:

```
brew install ruby@2.7
```

Switch to the newly installed Ruby version:

```
brew link --overwrite ruby@2.7
```

Then install CocoaPods:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: it says "ruby@2.7 has been deprecated because it is not supported upstream!"

Answer (score 9):

Please use this below code: -

`arch -x86_64 pod install`

This will definitely work, under any circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

**Working in Sept 2021, Mac M1**

I just want to add to [Medhi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64919058/12834539), to do a "pod repo update" within the same terminal inside the iOS folder, because that was critically fixing the error for me.

Here's the complete To-do-list:

1. Duplicate the Terminal application in the Utilities folder.
2. Right click on the app and choose "Get Info".
3. Rename the other version of the app as you like.
4. Check the option "open with Rosetta".
5. Install Cocoapods with the command `sudo gem install cocoapods`
6. Type the command line `sudo gem install ffi` to fix the ffi bundle problem.
7. **Go to the iOS folder of your app in the same terminal**
8. **Do `pod repo update`**
9. Now you can do a `pod install` without a problem.

Comment: Could you please link to the answer you're adding to instead of the user auspicious99? They have edited two answers to this question and it's not clear which one you meant to add to. You can copy the link to an answer using the "Share" button below it and [edit] your post to contain the URL of the answer.

Comment: @LW001 I did the edit - makes sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: oh gosh that was it!! pod repo update

Answer (score 7):

### **The following solution work for me on my Apple M1 machine.**

I've spent over a week searching for a solution to install CocoaPods successfully on a M1 machine. You may see if my method works for you or not.

**The solution requires the Terminal.app to be running in "*Rosetta*" mode.**

**But it does not required the Terminal to be running in x86.**

[Environment]

Mac mini (M1, 2020) / macOS Big Sur (Version 11.5.2) / Xcode Version 13.0 (13A233)

---

### Terminal + Rosetta

### (Rosetta is required on CocoaPods installation)

To run the terminal.app in "*Rosetta*" mode,

Right click the Terminal.app > Select "*Get Info*" > Make sure "*Open using Rosetta*" is checked.

[image: Image showing a checkbox with item "Open using Rosetta" is checked.]

---

### Steps

**(1) Run the following lines for updating gem.**

Make sure you gem version is up-to-date before executing any commands following. The update is introduced by [this article](https://medium.com/codex/simple-way-to-use-cocoapods-on-m1-ac9e22cf7e1c) on Medium.

```
sudo gem update -n /usr/local/bin --system

sudo gem install  -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods --pre
```

**(2) Execute the commands using the "sudo" command.**

```
sudo gem install
```

**(3) Install an older version of CocoaPods**

As the latest version (1.10.0) cannot be installed for my case. I've tried installing an older version. The line execute successfully without any error messages.

You may check [the thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668456?login=true) on Apple's forum.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

---

### Solutions on Error

Then, the compiler may bring you some error, like "*active developer path do not exist*". This error would shown **if you've installed a beta version** of Xcode on your machine.

You would need run following lines for the compiler to switch to a new active path, pointing to the new Xcode app.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch ／Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

If your Xcode **refuses to switch**, you may check out [this thread](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi1xriLkqLzAhUOEqYKHQv9B98QFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fforums%2Fthread%2F13629&usg=AOvVaw1JRuJTuuKCFvT_hPPlhzBq) on Apple's forum to see if it helps.

---

### Final Step

**(1) Uncheck "*Open using Rosetta*"**

Then, may go back to the "info" panel and uncheck "*Open using Rosetta*", but unchecking Rosetta is optional. You may keep the box checked if it is needed.

**(2) Run CocoaPods commands as usual**

After that, you can back to the project directory and run commands `pod init` to initiate the CocoaPods for your project as usual

Steps for a normal CocoaPods build:

1. `pod init`
2. `open Podfile`
3. `edit Podfile` (for specifying pods)
4. `pod install`
5. The *.xcworkspace* is ready to be opened in Xcode.

*Use `sudo xcodebuild -license` if you've faced an error (regarding to Xcode registration).*

Answer (score 6):

Install cocoapods

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Install pod file

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Update pod

```
arch -x86_64 pod update
```

Answer (score 6):

Pod Not installing on **M1 Chip MAC** ??? No worries

run below three commands : -

```
pod deintegrate

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod install
```

it works !!

Comment: only answer that actually worked

Answer (score 6):

Mac M1 MacOS **BigSur** solution:

```sh
brew cleanup -d -v    
brew install cocoapods
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me I am on mac M2 Ventura.

Answer (score 5):

If your case is that you've updated your project and already have ffi installed, you will need to run this:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 4):

Try $ sudo gem install ffi. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

this is what i got when trying to instal ffi in native terminal:

```
Fetching ffi-1.13.1.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/ext/ffi_c
```

switching to Rosetta enabled terminal, installing "gem install cocoapods" fails on

```
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

but then installation of ffi was successful...

Finally solved it with

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 4):

As of version `1.10.1` Jan 7, 2021, CocoaPods is now supporting the new M1 chip.

Comment: I have this version, but I still need to prefix all commands with `arch -x86_64`

Comment: @tontonCD if you're coming from an older version, uninstalling and reinstalling CocoaPods might fix this for you. please confirm if you had the chance to do so.

Comment: No, sorry, my M1 is new, it's the first time I install cocoa pod. It suggests that uninstalling is not sufficient... but perhaps mandatory...

Answer (score 4):

**IN MAC M1**, for anyone using KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile), but it may work for other, finding that it does not create files on the `.xcworkspace` for the iOS APP, when using CocoaPods as dependency manager, first install CocoaPods by typing

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

than navigate to your project folder, now on the iOS folder and type

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Now you should find all the files in iOS workspace.
If you have problems with

```
/Users/$name/$directory/$projectName/$iosFolderName/$iosAppName.xcodeproj 
The linked and embedded framework 'Pods_iosApp.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64.
```

You need to add **arm64** to xCode, click on the project folder -> **Build Settings** -> and search for **Excluded Architectures** and add **arm64**

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved my problem in M1. Someone might be helped.

From System preference. User & group. Set login shell as

```
   /bin/bash
```

Then close the terminal and reopen it.run this command

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

Hopefully, this will works.

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same issue. I did find that the cocoa pods UI app seems to work as expected.

Comment: This is underrated. Any of the previous comments didn't help me, and I only needed to run one demo.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and this is what helped me. Open the terminal and type the below command :

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
```

Answer (score 3):

For updating pods, maybe someone will help:

After installing ffi:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Update dependencies

```
arch -x86_64 pod update
```

Answer (score 3):

I have got solution for this for cocoapods installation.

There is basically 2 ways to install cocoa pods.

**1. install cocoapods via Homebrew:**

```
brew install cocoapods
```

**2. install cocoapods via gem:**

```
sudo gem install ffi
```

if you are facing issue with **Apple M1** or **Apple M2** chip

First terminal with Rosetta

- Right click on the Terminal application and select op.
- Right click on the app and choose "Get Info".
- Check the option "open with Rosetta".

[image]

you may go for following command:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

once finish installation try with following command:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

**Install pod in project without using rosetta terminal**
just follow below steps

- sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
- arch -x86_64 pod install

Answer (score 1):

I have a twist to this answer:

1. run

```
sudo gem install ffi
```

2. **the twist**: *I restarted my machine* and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my new MacBook Air M1 just because m1 has a different architecture we should install packages with [Rosetta Translation Environment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment).

You can solve most compatibilities by using rosetta.

## STEPS TO SOLVE:

1. Open finder/applications
2. Duplicate your terminal
3. Right-click the new terminal and check the checkbox
   [x] open using

and then install packages with this terminal
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you Are using M1 chip system then use-

go to application folder-

select terminal open with rosseta-
then run cmd-

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Then

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate of other earlier answers. Opening with Rosetta isn't required

Comment: Did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Click right and open get info menu
Check "Open using rosetta"

sudo gem install cocoapods

sudo gem install ffi

sudo gem update --system // Update ruby

If it doesn't work:

Install a ruby manager, I preferred [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

rvm install:

> - $brew install gnupg

- gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
- \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash

Don't forget to add bash profile:

> export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to path for scripting (to
> manage Ruby versions) export PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH" [[ -s
> "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # Load
> RVM into a shell session *as a function*

- Check

> $rvm -list

command if rvm is installed successfully

- Install new ruby version:

> $rvm install 3.1.2

- Select default version:

> $rvm --default use 3.1.2

Then restart the terminal and run $sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Tried 10 other suggestions. THIS ONE WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

I did get this problem after new dependencies (Firebase) where added to the repo. Was then able to do the sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi, but other problems remained after it.

My fix was:
**re-cloning the repo** and running it again.

*Setup: Xcode 12.4 Mac M1 react-native 63.4*

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was to add arch -x86_64 at the begining of the create command

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, trying to build app on Mac M1

first go to your `applications` folder and

select `terminal` app -> get info -> `select run with rosseta`

`// if you are trying to build the app through xcode`
Repeat the above steps for `xcode` app

Note: Make sure your terminal and code are closed while doing so.

Now run your terminal switch to your `project_folder/ios`

Run below-shown commands

```
sudo gem install cocoapods

sudo gem install ffi

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above solutions are valid, just wanted to post that with home brew and cocoapods supports native Apple Silicon chips you can run the command without prefixing `arch -x86_64`

so, `sudo gem install ffi` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

**we can easily fix this problem**

1. Click on Finder
2. go to applications
3. right click on xcode
4. click on get info
5. checkmark the open using Rosetta
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

As of Nov 2022. Did the following on a 2021 M1 iMac and it works.

```
# uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

# Optional; unshallow homebrew core
git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow

# Install homebrew to right locations; from https://brew.sh/
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
# Add shortcuts as prompted at the end of running the above command
echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

# Install cocoapods
brew install cocoapods

# Further, install Vim; taken from https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/vim
brew install vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `ARCHFLAGS` can be used to create a univeral binary install of `cocoapods` with the system Ruby shipped by Apple.

```bash
sudo env ARCHFLAGS='-arch arm64 -arch arm64e -arch x86_64' \
  gem install cocoapods

## needed for compatibility with system Ruby currently shipping with Ventura 
sudo env ARCHFLAGS='-arch arm64 -arch arm64e -arch x86_64' \
  gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.3

## verify that universal binaries were installed:
CHECK_DIR="/Library/Ruby"
find "$CHECK_DIR" -name "*.bundle" | xargs file

# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/ffi_c.bundle: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64] [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e]
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/ffi_c.bundle (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/ffi_c.bundle (for architecture arm64):   Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/ffi_c.bundle (for architecture arm64e):  Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c/ffi_c.bundle:                       Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64] [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e]
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c/ffi_c.bundle (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c/ffi_c.bundle (for architecture arm64): Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c/ffi_c.bundle (for architecture arm64e):    Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle:                             Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64] [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e]
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle (for architecture arm64):   Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle (for architecture arm64e):  Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e
```

Tested on both an Apple Intel mini and an Apple Silicon mini. Each had a clean macOS Ventura 13.4 install with Xcode 14.3.1 (14E300c) on the boot drive.

The Apple Intel mini can create a universal binary with multiple Instruction Set Architecture (ISA) slices. However, the Intel can only run and test the native `x86_64`. The Apple Silicon mini with Rosetta enabled can run|test all of the `arm64`, `arm64e`, and `x86_64` ISA binary slices.

Answer (score 0):

For an M1 Mac and Gem/Ruby issues, read this (October 2023):

(First of all you should use **homebrew** to install **rbenv** and **gem**, links below):
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/brew-gem
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rbenv-bundler

Here we go:

- Install ruby/gem version:
- - sudo rbenv install 3.1.4 [or another version that you want]
- - rbenv global 3.1.4 [or another version that you want]
- confirm ruby version installed (and which is in use):
- - rbenv versions
- - which -a ruby
- - ruby -v (should match with version installed)
- remove gem:
- - rm -rf ~/.gem/
- Install gem using rbenv:
- - sudo rbenv exec gem install bundler
- gem environment (to confirm your paths)

Note when running this you should use APP dir:

- bundle install (Inside APP dir)
- npm install && npm run pod-install

Answer (score -1):

If you are on an older project that needs to be ported over don't forget to update the project.pbxproj files in your Runner.xcodeproj and Pods.xcodeproj.

The IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET probably is still pointed towards 8.0

Update all occurrences as follows:

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 9.0;
```