# Could not find module 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arm64

I have an iOS project in swift.

When I run this project on my **intel MacBook**, it successfully runs the build. However, when I run the same project on my **M1 MacBook**, I get the following error:

> Could not find module 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator

I have tried running the build several times, and I even tried deleting the DrivedData folder many times, but no luck. I have also tried changing Architectures to armv7 x86_64 arm64 in build settings.

I am using XCode 13.1.

How can I debug this project to resolve the error?

Comment: Have a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65401237/2227743) and the related links? Looks promising.