# Unable to run python package AIBenchmark on 13 inch m1 MacBook Pro

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, apple-silicon

I got a new m1 MacBook Pro and installed the TensorFlow 2 provided by Apple, and I decided to do some testing for the MacBook, so I installed the python3 package "AIBenchmark", and the process was successful without any error messages. However, when I imported it, the following error message appeared.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
> File "/Users/andrew/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ai_benchmark/__init__.py",
> line 5, in <module>
>     from ai_benchmark.utils import *
> File "/Users/andrew/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ai_benchmark/utils.py",
> line 10, in <module>
>     from PIL import Image
> File "/Users/andrew/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py",
> line 94, in <module>
>     from . import _imaging as core ImportError: dlopen(/Users/andrew/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so,
> 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>   /Users/andrew/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so:
> mach-o, but wrong architecture
>   /Users/andrew/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so:
> mach-o, but wrong architecture
> ```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Which TF you had installed? is it the macos fork or which?

Comment: My TensorFlow version is 2.4.0-rc0

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that since [AI Benchmark](https://pypi.org/project/ai-benchmark/) has not been updated since Dec. 18, 2019, the library is an Intel architecture binary. I don't know the details of the python 3.8 installation via the Xcode Command Line Tools, but I imagine it's a universal binary (both Intel and Apple Arm64 architecture). My guess is that you'll have to run TensorFlow as an Intel binary, so I would try the following in the terminal: precede your command to startup your app with

`arch -x86_64`

Or, configure Terminal to run under Rosetta2.

1. Right-click on Terminal in Finder
2. Get Info
3. Open with Rosetta

More suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/65164150#65164150) (no, it's not python or TensorFlow related, but yes, it's relevant).