# Error when installing pods on Apple Silicon (M1)

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, apple-silicon

This is the error that I receive when entering "pod install" in AppCode

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:74:in `cdn_url?'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:36:in `create_source_with_url'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:21:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1073:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/[user]/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AppCode-ARM/ch-0/203.7148.89/AppCode.app/Contents/bin/pod:6:in `load'
/Users/[user]/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AppCode-ARM/ch-0/203.7148.89/AppCode.app/Contents/bin/pod:6:in `<main>'
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/64901980), but I still receive the same error.

I did notice that my cocoapods is installed under "Users", but not sure if that matters.

Comment: This is better addressed as an issue on the respective project(s).

Comment: This is a brand new project and no code has been written yet

Comment: I mean for the [Cocoapods project](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues).