# An error occured while installing pod 'CLTypingLabel'. I don't know how to fix it. I have tried many time. Please someone help me

Tags: ios, cocoapods

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.2.1 (20D74)
       Xcode : 12.4 (12D4e)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories :
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Flash Chat iOS13' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Flash Chat iOS13
  pod 'CLTypingLabel'

end
```

#### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:74:in `cdn_url?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:36:in `create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:21:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1073:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.0%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+missing+compatible+arch+in+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.0%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.0%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new
arunodhaiv@Arunodhais-MacBook-Air Flash-Chat-iOS13 %

Comment: Try to follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. It might something to do with my M1 MacBook. So I use this solution, and  problem solved.

[Running Cocoapods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1)

Install this first,

sudo gem install ffi

Then repeat the pod init and install.

Comment: [try this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10598), 

It worked for me.
`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
`arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: I think I wound up installing it with brew.  I don't quite remember, but I did get it working.  Thank you for following up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my previous MacBook M1 which has an ARM processor so we have to specify in the XCode. [image]

Select the project > Select the Target > Build Settings > Excluded Architecture > Add **arm64** in the list.