# Error Regarding undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass for Flutter App / CocoaPod Error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

I'm having an error regarding my Flutter application. When I run the "flutter run" script in terminal, I'm getting the following error from Cocoapods: "Error output from CocoaPods: Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass" (as seen also by the attached picture). [image]

How do I go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Are you using Apple M1? I had this issue as well and after some research I find that it might be something to do with Rosetta. You can refer to [Running CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1).

I managed to solve this issue on my MacBook Air M1 by typing this in the terminal:

`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`

from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334677/13814270.

Comment: Is there any diff b/w running this command and changing the terminal option to "open with rosetta" fix?

Comment: I've installed this multiple times, not working.

Answer (score 153):

I was trying to run pod install command in ios folder.
@boonyongyang solution is necessary but it seemed that I had 2 `ffi`'s installed, so I had to also run it with `arch -x86_64` command

```bash
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
# go to ios folder then run
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

#### ** UPDATE **

There is a [new recommended method](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices) by flutter team as also mentioned by @Chandrashekar-Ollala

```bash
sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

Comment: Good answer but it might be good to mention that you have to run all suggested fixes from flutter also with this new prefix. For example:

"pod update Firebase/Messaging" ->
"arch -x86_64 pod update Firebase/Messaging"

Comment: mine was solved by adding "--repo-update" after "arch -x86_64 pod install", so complete command was -> arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

Comment: Tip: If you're getting "CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install." after running the above instructions, close down your IDE entirely and shut down your simulators. Then, restart everything, in order for CocoaPods to reload.

Answer (score 46):

I struggled for many hours to figure this out, none of the solutions from Stack Overflow worked. Finally, I found this note in official Flutter documentation.

[image]

This problem arises on computers running on M1 chip. Just run the following code snippet in your terminal and everything works fine.

```
 sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

Comment: that's work for me, BTW after this, I need to run the pod repo update. Thank you

Comment: Thanks this worked for me , i also need to run pod repo update.

Comment: It's asking me which version to uninstall - one of 3 versions or all of them. What to do?

Comment: I would have uninstalled all of them. But be cautious as the deleted version can be a dependency of some other tool.

Answer (score 4):

I found solution in other command. Any `ffi` installation/re-installation didn't help.

I had to clear all cocoapods caches manually to fix the issue.
`sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos` and then `pod install`.

Answer (score 3):

the correct answer didnt work for me so i **deleted the Pod.lock** file and applied this steps:

Cocoa Pods Installation in M1

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Install ffi

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

#update repo

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Flutter iOS builds

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios
```

Answer (score 1):

On my MacBook M1 that issue came up when I accidentally added an blank line to the `pubspec.yaml` file. Deleting the line solved the issue (it looks like you can't have two empty lines one after another).

Comment: what exactly are you talking about, where is this file? why would you play with it? what does it do?

Comment: See here https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec

Answer (score 0):

In my case the pivotal thing was installing ruby (I used 3.1.2) for x86_64.

For achieving this I needed to:

- run terminal using rosetta
- install brew for x86_64
- install rvm
- install ruby 3.1.2 for x86_64
- `bundle install` in ios folder
- `pod install` in ios folder

Answer (score -2):

```
remove Podfile.lock
flutter clean
flutter build ios
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Maybe this info helps https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help