# Pod install error : Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ios, cocoapods, apple-silicon

Running `Pod install` on a Macbook M1 is giving me the following error (Cocoapods v1.12.1)

`` Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass ``
if I alter the content of my Podfile (like adding a new Pod)

The `Pod install` command succeeds on an untouched version of my Podfile.

`Pod update` also succeeds.

I already tried all the tricks described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443265/error-regarding-undefined-method-map-for-nilnilclass-for-flutter-app-cocoap)  (`arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`, `arch -x86_64 pod install`, `sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc`) with no luck.

Already tried to uninstall Cocoapods and reinstall with homebrew, wipe off Cocoapods from my project with `pod deintegrate`, `pod clean cache -all` , etc...

Running out of ideas : /