Flutter - Firebase Core - Error Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
I am trying to configure my Flutter app with Firebase and am having no luck just getting the app to run after adding firebase_core: ^3.1.0
Here's what has happened thus far.

flutter pub add firebase_core

tried launching the app and received the following error:
Error: The plugin "firebase_core" requires a higher minimum iOS deployment version than your application is targeting. To build, increase your application's deployment target to at least 13.0 as described at https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios

Modified the ios/PodFile by uncommenting the following line and change '12.0' to '13.0'
platform :ios, '13.0'

Then I got the following error:
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.


Any assistance is appreciated.

Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70238542/833395

First, in your project go to "/iOS" then "/podfile", in the top of the file you will see this line
# platform :ios, '12.0'

just uncomment it and change the iOS version from 12 to 13: so it should be like this:
platform :ios, '15.6' 

If you don't see the line just added normally at the top of the file.
Second, go to Xcode app and make sure you are at the iOS folder of the same project you work with, then just select "Runner" from the left list of folders, and go to "general" section, and change the "Minimum deployments" to "IOS 15.6".
Just make sure you have download cocoapods last version.
after running your project after the steps I mention it above, you may expect to see the terminal of the IDE you use is installing "pod", wait for it, because it will take long time depending on your internet connection.
that's all, and I hope it works for you.
Best luck

I tried many suggestions.
The following worked for me:
Error Regarding undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass for Flutter App / CocoaPod Error

