# How to change Cocoapods source for M1 Mac

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, apple-m1

I am using Macbook with M1 chip so that default installation of cocoapods doesn't work because of `Ruby` crash. I applied solution of installing independent ruby from below SO post. After I applied this solution, now I have two `Cocoapods` installation on my machine. One is on `/usr/local/bin/pod` (the default one which is not working with M1) and other is in `$(brew --prefix)/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/pod`.

**What I want to achieve:** When I run `Which pod` I want that path in `ruby/gems/3....` will shown so make that pod source path as default.

**P.S:** When I check my ruby and gem source with `Which gem` and `Which ruby` It shows right path. I tried to run `sudo gem install cocoapods` after uninstall it but didn't work.

[Solution I applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66556339/4908882)

Answer (score 1):

It might be all due to the good old path issues.
Just bring this line up to the first line of your `.zshrc`

`export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH`