# Ionic React App IOS Build fails 'provisioning profile'

Tags: ionic-framework, deployment, build, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I try to build my app for the IOS platform.
I am on windows thats why I cant use XCode and followed the Ionic appflow with fastlane.

I've generated certificates, profiles etc using the apple developer site and openssl according to this guide https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/package/credentials#ios-credentials

These are my errors:

> error: "App" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'App' from project 'App')

And fastlane summary shows that action "gym" failed

I am confused because some lines before the error is logged it says:

> Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"com.sebastian.IonicTestApp"=>"Boehler IT Solutions Testing"}

Comment: Have you found a solution about this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/64901980#64901980

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I am using an Apple Mac Book with M1 Chip.

[Running CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/64901980#64901980)

This helped me solving the issue