# Cocoapods installation problem in apple m1

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, development-environment, apple-m1

This is the screenshot of the current situation. Its a Brand new Apple M1 MacBook. react is working fine but React-native is not getting installed properly. Tried various solutions but no luck.[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was able to do it natively.

Try this on native terminal.

```
brew install ruby #update to latest version
sudo gem install ffi 
sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo gem install ethon #update to latest version
```

Note: This worked for me. Can't guarantee the same would happen for you.

Answer (score 0):

run the following commands in the ios directory of your React Native project

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod install
```

refer to this

[Running CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1)

it is because of m1's architecture that you need to run different commands from those that are mentioned in the official docs of React Native