# I am trying to run a iOS app using flutter and this is the error I am getting after installing cocoa pods (error regarding pod install)

Tags: macos, flutter, cocoapods, pod-install

> System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in
> `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT
> (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

[image: Error image here]

This is the error I get after I try to run the app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: uninstalling cocoapods and installing and older version worked just fine for me and solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading pod using `pod upgrade` in IDE's terminal

Try these commands in terminal:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod install
flutter run
```

If you are using M1, this thread might help: [Running CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1)

Answer (score 0):

Delete podfile.lock

then :

pod install

pub get

and run your app.

Comment: I've faced this issue before, can you give more details which might help me remember what causes the error.

Comment: uninstalling cocoapods and installing and older version worked just fine for me

Comment: ahh yea, it is a Ruby issue.