# Building React Native IOS on Apple Silicon (M1) says -lDoubleConversion

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have a `react-native` project that I'm trying to run on IOS. It normally runs on intel-based Macs, but on my new Apple Silicon-based M1 Mac it fails when building by

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

Error

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening citybusapp.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace citybusapp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme citybusapp -destination id=BBE6A445-DE96-4442-AAFB-C19EF67A6578

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/citybusapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/citybusapp.build/Script-08A4A3CD28434E44B6B9DE2E.sh (in target 'citybusapp' from project 'citybusapp')
    cd /Users/akila/Company/Stack\ Technologies/projects/citybus-app/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/citybusapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/citybusapp.build/Script-08A4A3CD28434E44B6B9DE2E.sh

PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/citybusapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/citybusapp.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'citybusapp' from project 'citybusapp')
    cd /Users/akila/Company/Stack\ Technologies/projects/citybus-app/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/citybusapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/citybusapp.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh

Ld /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sltb.app/sltb normal (in target 'citybusapp' from project 'citybusapp')
    cd /Users/akila/Company/Stack\ Technologies/projects/citybus-app/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphonesimulator -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXApplication -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXConstants -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXErrorRecovery -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXFileSystem -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXFont -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXImageLoader -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXKeepAwake -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXLinearGradient -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXLocation -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXSQLite -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXSecureStore -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXSplashScreen -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXUpdates -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXWebBrowser -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTTypeSafety -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCMaskedView -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNGestureHandler -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNScreens -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-CoreModules -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTBlob -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTNetwork -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTSettings -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTVibration -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-cxxreact -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsiexecutor -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsinspector -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMAppLoader -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMCore -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMPermissionsInterface -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMReactNativeAdapter -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-maps -L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-safe-area-context -F/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/citybusapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/citybusapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sltb.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/citybusapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/citybusapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sltb_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/citybusapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/citybusapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sltb.swiftmodule -ObjC -lDoubleConversion -lEXApplication -lEXConstants -lEXErrorRecovery -lEXFileSystem -lEXFont -lEXImageLoader -lEXKeepAwake -lEXLinearGradient -lEXLocation -lEXPermissions -lEXSQLite -lEXSecureStore -lEXSplashScreen -lEXUpdates -lEXWebBrowser -lFBReactNativeSpec -lFolly -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNCMaskedView -lRNGestureHandler -lRNReanimated -lRNScreens -lRNVectorIcons -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReactCommon -lUMAppLoader -lUMCore -lUMPermissionsInterface -lUMReactNativeAdapter -lYoga -lglog -lreact-native-maps -lreact-native-safe-area-context -lstdc++ -framework AudioToolbox -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MobileCoreServices -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/citybusapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/citybusapp.build/sltb.app-Simulated.xcent -lPods-citybusapp -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/citybusapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/citybusapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sltb_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sltb.app/sltb
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXApplication'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXConstants'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXErrorRecovery'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXFileSystem'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXFont'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXImageLoader'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXKeepAwake'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXLinearGradient'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXLocation'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXSQLite'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXSecureStore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXSplashScreen'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXUpdates'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXWebBrowser'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTTypeSafety'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCMaskedView'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNGestureHandler'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNScreens'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-CoreModules'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTBlob'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTNetwork'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTSettings'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTVibration'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-cxxreact'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsiexecutor'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsinspector'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMAppLoader'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMPermissionsInterface'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UMReactNativeAdapter'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-maps'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-safe-area-context'
ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


objc[10576]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x2074b7b78) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1162502b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[10576]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x2074b7bc8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x116250308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/akila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/citybusapp-clzpmuldcreidmfdgfievwmltnjv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sltb.app/sltb normal
(1 failure)
```

Based on a Github workaround, I tried to run Terminal using rosetta, but the issue remains the same: [Running CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/64901980)

Answer (score 1):

Try with below command:

```
arch -x86_64 npx react-native run-ios
```

it's worked for me