# Crash with cocoa pods env

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods

I am following a tutorial to create an IOS app using a Google Maps with cocoa pods.

The command `pod install` crashes. I am thinking of a env problem because the command `pod env` crashes...

I have tried to open an issue on cocoa github but they as closed it immediately as "not an issue of cocoa pods" without giving any help...

I have tried to reinstall homebrew, ruby, xcode command tools line as I have seen it on some posts.

```
➜  ~ which ruby
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
➜  ~ ruby -v
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [arm64-darwin21]
```

Here is the log trace

```
➜  ~ pod env              
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:36: [BUG] Illegal instruction at 0x00000001041ec000
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:                    
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                     
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                      
   for more details.                                                        
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.     

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0044 p:---- s:0260 e:000259 CFUNC  :getdtablesize
c:0043 p:0050 s:0256 e:000255 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:36
c:0042 p:0075 s:0253 e:000252 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:27
c:0041 p:0007 s:0250 e:000249 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:3
c:0040 p:0007 s:0247 e:000246 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0039 p:---- s:0244 e:000243 CFUNC  :require
c:0038 p:0110 s:0239 e:000238 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0037 p:0128 s:0227 e:000226 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curl.rb:29
c:0036 p:0007 s:0224 e:000223 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curl.rb:14
c:0035 p:0049 s:0221 e:000220 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curl.rb:9 [FINISH]
c:0034 p:---- s:0218 e:000217 CFUNC  :require
c:0033 p:0110 s:0213 e:000212 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0032 p:0049 s:0201 e:000200 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:16 [FINISH]
c:0031 p:---- s:0198 e:000197 CFUNC  :require
c:0030 p:0110 s:0193 e:000192 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0029 p:0013 s:0181 e:000180 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0028 p:---- s:0178 e:000177 CFUNC  :require
c:0027 p:0110 s:0173 e:000172 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0026 p:0006 s:0161 e:000160 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440
c:0025 p:0045 s:0153 e:000152 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372
c:0024 p:0318 s:0142 e:000141 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365
c:0023 p:0006 s:0132 e:000131 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338
c:0022 p:0059 s:0127 e:000126 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53
c:0021 p:0021 s:0123 e:000122 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31
c:0020 p:0030 s:0118 e:000117 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30 [FINISH]
c:0019 p:---- s:0113 e:000112 CFUNC  :new
c:0018 p:0068 s:0108 e:000104 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315 [FINISH]
c:0017 p:0039 s:0100 E:0005a8 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322
c:0016 p:0007 s:0093 e:000092 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331 [FINISH]
c:0015 p:---- s:0089 e:000088 CFUNC  :map
c:0014 p:0006 s:0085 e:000084 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331
c:0013 p:0008 s:0079 e:000078 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26
c:0012 p:0004 s:0075 e:000074 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60
c:0011 p:0016 s:0071 e:000070 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173
c:0010 p:0070 s:0067 e:000051 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77
c:0009 p:0012 s:0045 e:000044 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/env.rb:38
c:0008 p:0006 s:0041 e:000039 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/env.rb:26
c:0007 p:0011 s:0036 e:000034 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/env.rb:20
c:0006 p:0078 s:0031 e:000030 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334
c:0005 p:0024 s:0024 e:000023 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52
c:0004 p:0378 s:0019 e:000018 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0013 e:000012 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0109 s:0008 E:000cc0 EVAL   /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:000770 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/env.rb:20:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/env.rb:26:in `report'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/env.rb:38:in `stack'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'

[...]

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

[1]    19216 abort      pod env
```

PS : I am on Mac M1 version 12.0.1 and Xcode 13.1

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK so the solution is following:

1. I enabled Rosetta for the Terminal app. (Don't forget to re-open the app afterwards.) I don't know if this is step is necessary but I did it like that and it worked so if you skip this step and the following steps are not working, try also this one

[image: Enable Rosetta for the Terminal app]

2. Install ffi

   ```
   sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
   ```
3. Re-install dependencies

   ```
   arch -x86_64 pod install
   ```

The original solution is here: [How to running CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1)