# Invalid Podfile file unexpected template EOS

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

i have battling with this error for days now, trying to start up at a new job. Having issues while trying to run pod install on a react native cli project, i have tried every possible solution on here, doesnt work with mine.

The errors:

```html
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: /Users/decagon/kumoafrica/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected <<
    template =<<~EOS
                ^
/Users/decagon/kumoafrica/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:40: unknown regexp options - ll
/Users/decagon/kumoafrica/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:41: dynamic constant assignment
        RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT=$(pwd)
                                         ^
/Users/decagon/kumoafrica/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:41: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name
/Users/decagon/kumoafrica/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
        RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT=$(pwd)
                                          ^.

 #  from /Users/decagon/kumoafrica/ios/Podfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
 >  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
 #  require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

The podfile:

```html
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'kumo' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'kumoTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "kumo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.17.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.67.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

if anything else is needed ask, please help.

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 14):

Don't know if this is helpful now but if you're running React Native from scratch on a M1 Chip machine I was able to fix this issue by doing:

```
cd ios
bundle install
bundle exec pod install
```

After hours of struggle this was the way to actually make for `pod install` work for me.

This same example can be found here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup under the "Creating a new application" section.

Comment: Had the same error output as the OP, and this was the solution. I will say documentation is very vague. "If you are having trouble with iOS..."

Comment: For anyone on an Intel based mac wondering if this answer is for M1 macs only, I was having the same EOS error on my Intel mac and I gave this answer a shot and it worked. I should add that did uninstall cocoapods and reinstall it using brew as well

Answer (score 5):

I think you are Mac M1 user, so follow this steps :

1. Uninstall the local cocoapods gem

   ```
   sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
   ```
2. install Homebrew

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```

   or
   [Go to Site Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1)
3. Finally install cocoapods via Homebrew

   ```
   brew install cocoapods
   ```

And it will Work, Otherwise check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1)

Answer (score 4):

I was seeing this error as I was having a wrong version of cocoapods or pod. I somehow installed cocoapods from cask using `brew install --cask cocoapods` and that had an outdated version - `1.5.2` while latest version(at the time of writing) was `1.12.0`

To fix this issue, I had to then uninstall outdated cocoapods package using `brew uninstall --cask cocoapods` and reinstalled a latest version using
`brew install cocoapods` and then do `brew link cocoapods`

PS: You can check versions using `pod --version`