# Module 'firebase_core' not found

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to run my app on ios but could not fix this error. help please

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common, especially when adding in new firebase packages. Normally you just need to rebuild your pods. In the root of your project, enter these commands.

```
flutter clean
rm ios/podfile.lock
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install --repo-update
```

The final command will likely not work if you have an M1 mac and will need to do the following. [Taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334677/16816364)

```
# STEP 1: Install ffi
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

# STEP 2: Re-install dependencies
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build with Ionic, Cordova, Capacitor, DO NOT open the project File. Open the ios folder under Platforms.