# Unity Firebase iOS build Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, arm64

I'm trying to integrate Firebase to my Unity project for iOS platform following the official documentation. However, when i try to compile Unity build from XCode im facing issues like:

```css
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDatabaseReference", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppDatabase.a(database_reference_ios.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDatabase", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppDatabase.a(database_ios.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppApp.a(app_ios.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppApp.a(app_ios.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRTransactionResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppDatabase.a(database_reference_ios.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppApp.a(app_ios.mm.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

pls im begging on my knees

Answer (score 2):

Open `Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace` not `Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj`

if there is no `Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace`, run `pod install`

if you have a problem with cocoapods, reinstall cocoapods.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334677

Answer (score 0):

You must open the `.xcworkspace` file and **not** the `.xcodeproj` file!

To do this you need to:

1. CD your project into Terminal. Do this by typing in `cd`  and then drag-and-drop your entire project folder. Press enter.
2. Run the `pod install` command and press enter.

If you're using one of the latest M-series MacBook's than you need to run this command instead:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

If all goes well then a `.xcworkspace` file will be created and appear in your project folder. Close the previously open Xcode project and open this instead.