# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, realm, cocoapods

Trying to build react native app on ios(objective c) on RN version `0.66.4` and realm v `2.29.0`.

The podfile has the Realm version `3.17.3`

When trying to build, getting the following error:

```
  "realm::BpTreeBase::replace_root(std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::Array, std::__1::default_delete<realm::Array> >)", referenced from:
      realm::Column<long long>::replace_root_array(std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::Array, std::__1::default_delete<realm::Array> >) in libRealm.a(RLMCollection.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::EraseHandler::replace_root_by_leaf(realm::MemRef) in libRealm.a(RLMCollection.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::EraseHandler::replace_root_by_empty_leaf() in libRealm.a(RLMCollection.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::clear() in libRealm.a(RLMCollection.o)
      realm::Column<long long>::replace_root_array(std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::Array, std::__1::default_delete<realm::Array> >) in libRealm.a(RLMOptionalBase.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::EraseHandler::replace_root_by_leaf(realm::MemRef) in libRealm.a(RLMOptionalBase.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::EraseHandler::replace_root_by_empty_leaf() in libRealm.a(RLMOptionalBase.o)
      ...
  "realm::BpTreeBase::write_subtree(realm::BpTreeNode const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::BpTreeBase::SliceHandler&, realm::_impl::OutputStream&)", referenced from:
      realm::BpTree<long long>::write(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::_impl::OutputStream&) const in libRealm.a(RLMCollection.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::write(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::_impl::OutputStream&) const in libRealm.a(RLMOptionalBase.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::write(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::_impl::OutputStream&) const in libRealm.a(RLMAccessor.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::write(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::_impl::OutputStream&) const in libRealm.a(sync_permission.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::write(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::_impl::OutputStream&) const in libRealm.a(object_store.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::write(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::_impl::OutputStream&) const in libRealm.a(partial_sync.o)
      realm::BpTree<long long>::write(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::_impl::OutputStream&) const in libRealm.a(results.o)
      ...
```

There are lot of other similar errors of realm.
[image: Realm errors]

I tried

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
pod cache clean Realm
pod deintegrate || rm -rf Pods
pod install --verbose
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

but this didn't help me.

`podfile`:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Ajjas' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Pods for Ajjas

  pod 'Realm', '3.17.3',:modular_headers => true
  pod 'Avro-C', '1.7.6'
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '3.7.0'
  pod 'SocketRocket', '0.5.1'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics' # , '4.3.0'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics' #, '6.6.2'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10'

  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()
    # post_install do |installer|
    # end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    # installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    #   if target.name == 'React'
    #     target.remove_from_project
    #   end
    # end
  end
end
```

I am not sure is this a version problem, because this was working with older react-native version(`0.60.5`) (didn't give a try between `0.60.5` and `0.66.4` versions and directly jumped to `0.66.4`)

Using xcode version `13.4.1` on MacBook M1.

Any help on how to solve this problem will be much appreciated!

Comment: What ruby are you using?

Comment: @matt ruby version `ruby 2.6.8p205`

Comment: Right but is it the built-in ruby? Because if so, step one would be stop using that. The `cocoapods` gem (and all other gems) need to be in a user-installed ruby. If you have to say `sudo` to install gems, you're using the wrong ruby.

Comment: @matt, yes I believe it's the build-in ruby (`ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.x86_64-darwin21]`) , will this be causing this issue of the realm? The reason is, that it was working fine earlier with the older react-native version.

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause but it needs to be fixed so you might as well do that.

Comment: I just added ruby using `brew`, removed existing pods, run `pod install` again, and cleaned the build folder, but still having the same issue. :(

@matt Do you want some other or additional information to better understand how can this be solved?

Comment: It takes a lot more than "adding ruby". What does `which ruby` say? What does `which pod` say?

Comment: @matt Okay, here it is

`which ruby` - `/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.6/bin/ruby`

`ls -lh $(which pod)` - `/usr/local/bin/pod -> ../Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/bin/pod`

Comment: That seems okay! But as you say, it doesn't explain the issue. :(

Comment: I am just not able to figure out that why upgrading react native is causing this problem.

Comment: What version of CocoaPods is it? `pod --version`. Can you also include your podfile in the question? I had to update my podfile when I switched to the M1 so there may be something there.

Comment: @Jay `pod --version` is pod `1.11.3`.
I have updated the question, added the `podfile`

Comment: I believe your target needs to be iOS 13 or higher, update your podfile and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems.
I think it is related with "M1 chips", and libraries not ready for it..
https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3199

Tobe honest, I'm still not confident about the reason for this problem.
But anyway, I solved this problem through this flow.

1. I followed this flow from this link [How to run CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1?page=1&tab=trending#tab-top)

```
# Uninstall the local cocoapods gem
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

# Reinstall cocoapods via Homebrew
brew install cocoapods
```

but you may have problem installing cocoapods through homebrew also.
then follow this https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

2. Turn on "open with rosetta" on 'Xcode'

This flow magically solved my problem. It may not solve your problem, but I believe those links would give you hints to solve your problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I realised that I was using a pretty older version of realm(as the errors for undefined symbols were mostly of realm), so I upgraded the realm version to `10` and tried clean build and started fresh, and after that, I didn't got this error.

Comment: I was hoping this was just a M1-related problem, but I went back to my Intel-based Mac and it, unfortunately, had the same  problem. So I am stuck for the moment and looking for ideas.