# Flutter "An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile." Error running pod install

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, cocoapods, podfile, podfile-lock

I know there are many threads about this but even though I searched for days, none of them could solve my problem.

I am using macOS Monterey 12.5.1 M1 Chip. I tried the 2022 and 2021 solution written in the most fav solution at this address [How to run CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/65334677#65334677), but it did not improve.
While applying 'sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi' in 2021 solution, I get the error "arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable". The address says download rosetta as a solution, I download 'softwareupdate --install-rosetta' like this but this did not solve my problem.

I updated the Ruby version to 3.1.2 nothing changed,

and I tried;

- delete ios folder
- Flutter create .
- pod deintegrate ios folder
- pod install ios folder
- Flutter clean
- Flutter pub get
- Flutter run

error persists.

When I change the released sections in the project 'Runner' section in the podfile to debug, I can open the application in the simulator, but this time while trying the application on the real device, when I want to run the application again, a white screen comes and throws it from the application. Thanks in advance to those who can help.

Comment: Have you tried `arch x86_64 pod install`?

Comment: yes, but i give "arch: Can't find x86_64 in PATH" error.

Comment: Oh my mistake! for got this `-`. Write the command as: `arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: i give "arch: posix_spawnp: pod: Bad CPU type in executable" error.