# Cocoapods Segmentation Fault When Adding ‘google_sign_in’ Package to Flutter App (iOS Variant)

Tags: ios, flutter, google-api, cocoapods, google-signin

I can’t compile my Flutter App (iOS variant) when I added the package **google_sign_in**.  At first, the symptom had to do with f f i pods (whatever they are). As per the resulting error message, I uninstalled ffi and re-installed it with the **--enable-libffi-alloc** switch as follows:

```
sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

Now, I’m getting the following error:  Error output from CocoaPods:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/curls/infos.rb:127: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0xffffffffffffffa8

ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
```

Ive been looking for solutions to the above and the consensus seems to point to some pods incompatibility with my M1 processor. Ive been trying lots of suggestions for the past day, all to no avail, and I’m at wits end. Im hoping that somebody out there can help.

My environment is as follows:

```
Box: MacBook Air M1     
OS: Monterey 12.2     
Flutter Vers: 3.3.8     
google_sign_in package vers: 5.4.2
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

/Jose

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, just with the `firebase_core` package.

The solution is the same as for https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334677/515239

Install cocoapods via Homebrew instead of using the system installed gem/ruby:

```
# Uninstall the local cocoapods gem
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

# Reinstall cocoapods via Homebrew
brew install cocoapods
```

The preinstalled ruby is deprecated since MacOS Catalina:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes/

See also: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/do-not-use-mac-system-ruby-do-this-instead/

Comment: thanks for responding. I uninstalled cocoapods and reinstalled it via homebrew as per your suggestion, but now, my flutter build has the following error: 

'CocoaPods minimum required version 1.10.0 or greater not installed. Skipping pod install.' 

I checked the version of cocoapods that was installed and its 1.5.2.

Is there a specific switch to be passed to get the latest version of cocoapods via homebrew?

Comment: That is strange. `brew install cocoapods` should give you the latest version, which is 1.11.3 (stable): https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cocoapods

Maybe try:

    `brew update`
    `brew doctor`
    `brew upgrade cocoapods`