# CocoaPods installed but not working. Mac M1, Ventura 13.3.1

Tags: flutter, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm trying to run flutter on my Macbook but everytime I run `sudo flutter doctor`, I have this mesage:

```
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
      To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
```

I tried to install cocoapods dozens of times using Gem but still does not work. `sudo gem install cocoapods`

`pod --version 1.12.1`

`ruby --version ruby 3.0.0p0`

I already try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1), but does not work.

Comment: I'm having exact same issue...