# Nx cannot install `pod install` via `@nx/react-native:pod-install` on macOS M1 Silicon

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, monorepo, nrwl-nx

When trying to install pod packages for iOS with `nx run <my_package_name>:pod-install`, this occurs:

```
$ nx run app:pod-install

> nx run app:pod-install

Running `pod install` from "/Users/.../cites/packages/app/ios"
Command failed: pod install
Ignoring ffi-1.15.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.4
Ignoring ffi-1.15.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.4
Ignoring ffi-1.15.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.4
...
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file), '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
...
```

[image]

## Context

Environment:

- macOS M1 (Silicon)
- react@18.2.0
- react-dom@18.2.0
- react-native@0.71.8
- nx@16.3.0-beta.8"
- @nx/react-native@16.3.0-beta.8

Install pods via terminal `cd packages/app/ios && pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to a mismatch between my system architecture and the architecture that the `ffi gem` is trying to use. Specifically, it says that it's trying to use `ffi` version `1.15.5` for the arm64 architecture, but your system is `x86_64`.

This is a common issue when running certain Ruby gems on newer Macs with the M1 chip, which uses the arm64 architecture. However, most gems, including ffi, have been traditionally built for `x86_64`.

To use `Rosetta 2` in M1 chip, we need to translate the `x86_64` instructions to `arm64`.

The command lines to solve this solution are found here [How to run CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1).

## Steps

### 1 - Install global cocoapod package `ffi`

Open your terminal and run this command: `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`.

### 2 - Change the Nx package settings

In file `packages/<your_package_name>/project.json`.

I update the Nx command `run-ios` (default value on Nx [documentation](https://nx.dev/packages/react-native/executors/run-ios#examples)) and `pod-install`:

```json
    "run-ios": {
      "executor": "@nx/react-native:run-ios",
      "options": {
        "simulator": "iPhone 14 Pro Max",
        "install": false
      }
    },
    "pod-install": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "packages/app/ios",
        "command": "arch -x86_64 pod install"
      }
    },
    "pod-install-non-arm64": {
      "executor": "@nx/react-native:pod-install",
      "options": {}
    },
```

[image]

## Extra

I had little space on my Mac. While I was installing pod packages, Hermes Engine couldn't been installed.

The reason was Hermes Engine requires more than 1Gb of storage, as pointed here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31505#issuecomment-1050906080.

This was the error:

```
Installing ReactCommon (0.71.8)
Installing SocketRocket (0.6.0)
Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
Installing YogaKit (1.18.1)
Installing boost (1.76.0)
Installing fmt (6.2.1)
Installing glog (0.3.5)
Installing hermes-engine (0.71.8)
[!] Error installing hermes-engine
[!] /usr/bin/tar xf /var/folders/ys/spt316fs5sxck01gjy40s1rc0000gn/T/d20230526-23438-3wta30/file.tgz -C /var/folders/ys/spt316fs5sxck01gjy40s1rc0000gn/T/d20230526-23438-3wta30
./destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/Versions/0/hermes: Write failed
./destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/hermes.framework/hermes: Write failed
./destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/hermes.framework/Info.plist: Can't create 'destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/hermes.framework/Info.plist'
./destroot/include/jsi/: Can't create 'destroot/include/jsi'
./destroot/include/hermes/: Can't create 'destroot/include/hermes'
```