# got error when running react-native-tts on react native app on ios simulator on MacBook with M1 chip

Tags: ios, react-native, text-to-speech, apple-m1

I'm new to react-native and I'm learning by doing a voice chat app and I'm about running it on ios. Everything is okay until I use  [react-native-tts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tts) to convert text to speech. I got no error when installing it (**npm install --save react-native-tts**) and linking it to iOS (**npx pod-install**) but got errors when rerunning that app on an iOS simulator.

Apparently, The problem happened when I linked this library to ios  and because I'm using a **MacBook with chip M1**.  I have tried to fix this by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1). Specifically,  I follow those command:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods 
brew install cocoapods.
```

I also tried

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi 
arch -x86_64 pod install.
```

But it didn't work.

Did anyone already came up with that issue please ?

Here is error when run on Xcode
[Error when run on Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv3fm.png)

Here is Error when run on terminal in project folder (**npm run ios**)
[Error when run on terminal in project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYaM3.png)

Comment: I also tried to add those statements to podfile:  
```
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
   end 
```
But It didn't still work