# Kotlin MultiPlatform in Mac M1 error due to cocoapods

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to start kotlin multiplatform in my android studio project but I am unable to install cocoapods.

```
kdoctor                                                                                            ─╯
Environment diagnose (to see all details, use -v option):
[✓] Operation System
[✓] Java
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] Xcode
[✖] Cocoapods
  ✖ System ruby is currently used
    CocoaPods is not compatible with system ruby installation on Apple M1 computers.
    Please install ruby via Homebrew, rvm, rbenv or other tool and make it default
    Detailed information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/66556339#66556339
  ✖ Cocoapods are installed via Homebrew but not linked to /usr/local/bin
    Execute 'brew link --overwrite cocoapods'

Conclusion:
  ✖ KDoctor has diagnosed one or more problems while checking your environment.
    Please check the output for problem description and possible solutions.
```

I have run the command kdoctor but its telling Cocoapods is not compatible

```
kdoctor                                                                                            ─╯
Environment diagnose (to see all details, use -v option):
[✓] Operation System
[✓] Java
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] Xcode
[✖] Cocoapods
  ✖ System ruby is currently used
    CocoaPods is not compatible with system ruby installation on Apple M1 computers.
    Please install ruby via Homebrew, rvm, rbenv or other tool and make it default
    Detailed information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/66556339#66556339
  ✖ Cocoapods are installed via Homebrew but not linked to /usr/local/bin
    Execute 'brew link --overwrite cocoapods'

Conclusion:
  ✖ KDoctor has diagnosed one or more problems while checking your environment.
    Please check the output for problem description and possible solutions.
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately CocoaPods is not compatible with system ruby installation on Apple M1 computers.

So you need:

0. Uninstall Cocoapods `gem uninstall cocoapods`
1. Install ruby using Homebrew / rbenv / RVM / etc. (For Homebrew: `brew install ruby`)
2. Make it default, (For Homebrew: `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH`)
3. Install Cocoapods