# Cocoapods are installed via Homebrew but not linked to /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I run kdoctor from my kmm project and getting error

```
Environment diagnose (to see all details, use -v option):
[✓] Operation System
[✓] Java
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] Xcode
[✖] Cocoapods
  ✖ System ruby is currently used
    CocoaPods is not compatible with system ruby installation on Apple M1 computers.
    Please install ruby via Homebrew, rvm, rbenv or other tool and make it default
    Detailed information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/66556339#66556339
  ✖ Cocoapods are installed via Homebrew but not linked to /usr/local/bin
    Execute 'brew link --overwrite cocoapods'
```

using m1 chipset

```
 which ruby >>> returns
/usr/bin/ruby
```

also tried to export path but it loose value every time I restart studio, also doesn't resolve problem

```
which pod
/opt/homebrew/bin/pod
```

Answer (score 1):

Although kdoctor is telling that something is wrong, I pretty sure everything is fine.

Just to make this [✖] go away you can override system ruby and use Homebrew's version instead, by putting Homebrew's ruby path before in `PATH`:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
```

You can put this line in `.zshrc` and run `source ~/.zshrc` to apply changes.